# unable to create soap request using SAAJ

Tags: java, xml, soap, saaj

I am trying to make a `soap` request using `SAAJ` in java. I am trying to make following xml:
**required XML**

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:paygo="http://paygo24.com/v3/protocol" 
xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <tem:SendRequest>
      <paygo:request  xsi:type="paygo:RegisterCheckRequest"  Service="42" Id="7a646d45-ee2f-4b1c-8de8-780c416fbbd0">
          <PaymentParameters>
                 <Parameter Name="account" Value="08374829"/>
           </PaymentParameters>
      </paygo:request>
      <tem:pointId>46</tem:pointId>
      <tem:password>alkdsjflasdkjfl+ak87+UI90==</tem:password>
    </tem:SendRequest>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

**JAVA SAAJ**

```
package ussd.utils;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.soap.*;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

public class SOAPClientSAAJ {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        // Create SOAP Connection
        SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

        // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
        String url = "http://paygo24.com/v3/protocol";
        SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(), url);

        // print SOAP Response
        System.out.print("Response SOAP Message:");
        createSoapResponse(soapResponse);
       // soapResponse.writeTo(System.out);

        soapConnection.close();
    }

    private static void createSoapResponse(SOAPMessage soapResponse) throws Exception  {
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        Source sourceContent = soapResponse.getSOAPPart().getContent();
        System.out.println("\n----------SOAP Response-----------");
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
        transformer.transform(sourceContent, result);
     }

    private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest() throws Exception {
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
        SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();      
        envelope.removeNamespaceDeclaration(envelope.getPrefix());
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("SOAP-ENV","http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
        envelope.setPrefix("SOAP-ENV");              

        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("paygo","http://paygo24.com/v3/protocol");
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("tem","http://tempuri.org/");
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsd","http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsi","http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");


        SOAPHeader header=soapMessage.getSOAPHeader();                      
        header.setPrefix("SOAP-ENV");       
        SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
        soapBody.setPrefix("SOAP-ENV");
        SOAPElement root=soapBody.addChildElement(new QName("tem:SendRequest"));
        SOAPElement request=root.addChildElement(new QName("paygo:request")); 

        //SOAPElement root=soapBody.addChildElement(new QName("","tem:SendRequest"));      
        //SOAPElement request=root.addChildElement(new QName("","paygo:request"));       
        request.setAttribute("xsi:type", "paygo:RegisterCheckRequest");
        request.setAttribute("Id","7a646d45-ee2f-4b1c-8de8-780c416fbbd0");
        request.setAttribute("Service","42");        
        SOAPElement paymentParameters =request.addChildElement(new QName(" ","PaymentParameters"));

        SOAPElement parameter=paymentParameters.addChildElement("Parameter");        
        paymentParameters.setAttribute("xmlns","");
        parameter.setAttribute("Name","account");
        parameter.setAttribute("Value", "08374829");
        root.addChildElement("tem:pointId").setValue("46");       
        root.addChildElement("tem:password").setValue("alkdsjflasdkjfl+ak87+UI90==");           
        soapMessage.getSOAPHeader().detachNode();
        soapMessage.saveChanges();

        soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);


        return soapMessage;
    }

}
```

But I am getting following exception at `SOAPElement request=root.addChildElement(new QName("paygo:request"));` line.
**Exception**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NAMESPACE_ERR: An attempt is made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl.setName(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.ElementImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.ElementFactory.createElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPDocumentImpl.createElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.ElementImpl.createElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.ElementImpl.addElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.impl.ElementImpl.addChildElement(Unknown Source)
    at ussd.utils.SOAPClientSAAJ.createSOAPRequest(SOAPClientSAAJ.java:58)
    at ussd.utils.SOAPClientSAAJ.main(SOAPClientSAAJ.java:18)
```

Comment: Why you are using such low level API as SAAJ?

Comment: so, what should i use, what is other alternatives

Comment: You can generate service classes by WSDL, using any SOAP library (cxf http://cxf.apache.org/ for example) and than just call method, using plain java objects, without even touch XML or SOAP envelope.

Comment: client didn't provide me a WSDL file

Comment: Usually wsdl can be obtained as `SERVICE_URL` + `?wsdl` parameter, for example `http://ws.cdyne.com/emailverify/Emailvernotestemail.asmx?wsdl` But in your case http://paygo24.com/v3/protocol - only namespace, and service URL usually not match with namespace. Also I can recommend SOAPUI tool for testing purpose.

Comment: already tried not possible in this case & SOAPUI requires WSDL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this SOAP envelope creation code, it should create your desired format.

```
 private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest() throws Exception {
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
        SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();      
        envelope.removeNamespaceDeclaration(envelope.getPrefix());
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("SOAP-ENV","http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
        envelope.setPrefix("SOAP-ENV");              

        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("paygo","http://paygo24.com/v3/protocol");
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("tem","http://tempuri.org/");
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsd","http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsi","http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

        SOAPHeader header=soapMessage.getSOAPHeader();                      
        header.setPrefix("SOAP-ENV");       
        SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
        soapBody.setPrefix("SOAP-ENV");
        SOAPElement root=soapBody.addChildElement("SendRequest","tem");
        SOAPElement request=root.addChildElement("request","paygo");         
        request.setAttribute("xsi:type", "paygo:RegisterCheckRequest");
        request.setAttribute("Id","7a646d45-ee2f-4b1c-8de8-780c416fbbd0");
        request.setAttribute("Service","42");        
        SOAPElement paymentParameters =request.addChildElement("PaymentParameters");

        SOAPElement parameter=paymentParameters.addChildElement("Parameter");        
        paymentParameters.setAttribute("xmlns","");
        parameter.setAttribute("Name","account");
        parameter.setAttribute("Value", "08374829");
        root.addChildElement("pointId","tem").setValue("46");       
        root.addChildElement("password","tem").setValue("alkdsjflasdkjfl+ak87+UI90==");           
        soapMessage.getSOAPHeader().detachNode();
        soapMessage.saveChanges();

        soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);


        return soapMessage;
    }
```

Comment: I was able to make an exact xml request, but problem is, I am getting bad response exception : `SEVERE: SAAJ0008: Bad Response; Found
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Bad response: (302Found`

Comment: As per the error it seems your request is redirected some other url by server. If you have a option get the correct URL and try it out. Also try to debug using SOAPUI / TCPMON  by setup proxy and see what is the response your are getting.

Comment: thanks, buddy, I appreciate your efforts. Actually this being a bottleneck for us since last 2 weeks. Thanks again.